# How to accept input of Array of string in swagger UI Api (spring boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

How to accept input of Array of string in swagger UI Api ? (spring boot)

> What version of the library are you using? Is it the latest version?
>
> --io.springfox springfox-boot-starter 3.0.0

The version 2.9.2 swagger-ui  result is userId=value1&userId=v1&userId=v3

But version 3.0.0 swagger-ui  result is userId: value1|v2|v3，Caused an error to occur

How to configure ‘Query array[string]’ to look like version 2.9.2 ？

Below is my code in my REST api as parameter:

```
//controller:
@GetMapping
public Result list( UserDto user）

public class UserDto  {

 @ApiModelProperty(dataType = "List")
    private List<String> userId;
}
```